# cant write items which i took from websites ,into file

Tags: php, file

$dosya=fopen('a.txt','r');
$dosya2=fopen('f.txt','w');

```
function getTitle($satir) {

    $data = file_get_contents("http://$satir");

    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims',$data,$matches)?$matches[1]:null;

    $title=str_replace(",", null, $title);

    $title=str_replace("-", null, $title);

    $title=trim($title);

    $title= explode(" ",$title);

    foreach ($title as $val) {
        echo $val."<br>";
        fwrite($dosya2, $val)."<br>";    //??
    }

}
```

fclose($dosya);
fclose($dosya2);

?>
why does not it write into text file ?

Comment: Edited my answer. If the answer suits you, please, mark it as an answer as well, don't just run off. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you even open the file somewhere? If you opened it outside the scope of the function, you need to get it from the global scope. See [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
function getTitle($satir) {
    global $dosya2;

    $data = file_get_contents("http://$satir");

    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims',$data,$matches)?$matches[1]:null;

    $title=str_replace(",", null, $title);

    $title=str_replace("-", null, $title);

    $title=trim($title);

    $title= explode(" ",$title);

    foreach ($title as $val) {
        echo $val."<br>";
        fwrite($dosya2, $val)."<br>";    //??
        }

    fclose($dosya2);
    }
```

Another point, is that some machines might not display the file before you actually close it. So add the fclose to the end of the script as I did as well. Try the code I pasted and let us know. Make sure your file is opened.

Another point is about code style. It's good to keep your code structure on point and readable. If your function says getTitle, then you should use the function to get the title, not to write it into a file. Maybe create a separate writer function for this case. Or if it's the only place where you're writing, rename the function. It's not a fault, it's just "bad style".

Edit - I see you edited your code. Your files get closed before the function gets fired. That's because when you include the file into your PHP page which you're using, it parses the whole file. Your file starts with opening the file and ends with closing them. So PHP opens the files and closes them right away. You need to have a separate function to close the files if you wish to do that. My advise would be to use a completely separate function to read / write the files, so you wouldn't use the memory uselessly. Open the file when you need to read it and close it when you're done, open the file when you need to write and close it when you're done.